# To add output and target folder links for each build step executed in Jenkins on the Jenkins Job page

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Is there a possibility to add separate links for each build step executed within the Jenkins job on to the Job page so that the developer can click on the links and can traverse directly to the path where the output files are present, log files are present for that specific build step?
Something of this format -
Build Step - Shell Execution
Target Folder - Link to Target Folder
Log Folder - Link to Log Folder

Comment: Can anyone help on this? any chance on any alternatives or plugins available that can help to achieve the above mentioned requirement?